# Postgresql VARADIC function, need help (beginner)

Tags: arrays, postgresql, function, plpgsql

I´m new in programming with plpgsql and stored functions in postgresql. 
I´ve programmed one function called this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.uploadbutton(VARIADIC arr character varying[])
RETURNS text
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$DECLARE
arrayi ALIAS for $1;

result text;
begin

return result;

END;
$function$
;
```

As you can see, the function does not have many code. The problem is that i don´t really understand how to handle Arrays in Postgresql and plpgsql.

I need to split the array every 3 delimeters until the end of array, the array can have many inputs but minimum 3.

```
SELECT uploadbutton('59373033336415021231','5','a','59373033335915022fff','5','b')
```

Here an example for calling it.

The output should look like that:

```
('59373033336415021231','5','a')('59373033336415021231','5','a')
```

Can you teach me, how to handle that ?

Kind regards guys!

EDIT:

After getting this Result :

```
('59373033336415021231','5','a')('59373033336415021231','5','a')
```

I need to put every 3 parameters, and call a second function with the first part of the result as parameters. And the second Value have to be Int. This should look like this:

edit('59373033336415021231',5,'a')
and the same for the second part of the result
edit('59373033336415021231',5,'a')

I´m trying it at the moment and want to get the id of the first parameter with my edit() function. This is what i have:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.upload(string_in text)
RETURNS integer
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$DECLARE
string_in ALIAS FOR $1;

 id integer;

 begin
id= (select id from public.buttons where fbisn = 
 split_part(string_in,',',1));

 return val;
 end;

$function$
;
```

string_in is everytime the for clause of the first function is completed, the result string of that. This function will be called every time.

But currently, i will get no result.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you add a sample of how the output should look like?

Comment: The output should look like that:

('59373033336415021231','5','a')('59373033336415021231','5','a')

Comment: Thanks for editing the question, i´m new here. :)

Comment: I would strongly advise against this. Don't munge different things into a single gigantic parameter array. Create three input parameters that match the three different things you want to pass, that way you can also give them the correct data types, e.g. `uploadbutton(p_codes int[], p_numbers int[], p_text text[])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a [`FOR LOOP`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONTROL-STRUCTURES-LOOPS) using `BY 3` is what you're struggling with

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.uploadbutton(VARIADIC arr TEXT[])
RETURNS TEXT LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE result TEXT DEFAULT '';
BEGIN
FOR i IN 1..array_length($1,1) BY 3 LOOP
  result := result || '(' || array_to_string($1[i:i+2],',') || ')';
END LOOP;
RETURN result;
END;
$$;
```

Testing

```
SELECT uploadbutton(VARIADIC '{"59373033336415021231","5","a","59373033335915022fff","5","b"}'::text[]);
                     uploadbutton                     
------------------------------------------------------
 (59373033336415021231,5,a)(59373033335915022fff,5,b)
(1 Zeile)
```

If you need the quotation marks `'` in every element, just change the concatenation of the `result` variable accordingly:

```
result := result || E'(\'' || array_to_string($1[i:i+2],E'\',\'') || E'\')';
```

**Edit**: see comments

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.uploadbutton(VARIADIC arr TEXT[])
RETURNS VOID LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE slice TEXT[];
BEGIN
FOR i IN 1..array_length($1,1) BY 3 LOOP
  slice := $1[i:i+2];
  PERFORM edit(slice[1]::TEXT,slice[2]::INT,slice[3]::TEXT);
END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for this nice code. I have used it and tried to make expand it, but i ran into the next problem. 
I want to use every 3 values with to execute a second function like this:

    select insertfunction(59373033336415021231,5,a)

Than the same function for the second and so on and so on. can you help me with this ? This is how i changed your function:

 
    FOR i IN 1..array_length($1,1) BY 3 LOOP
    insertquery :=  result || E'\'' || array_to_string($1[i:i+2],',') || E'\')';
    result = upload(insertquery);

Comment: Hi @ChristophD, does this second function get an array with 3 values in a single parameter or does it get 3 different parameters?

Comment: @ChristophD btw, can you edit your question with this info and also with the error message you're getting? Also explain a bit what the function `upload` does and what it returns :) If I see it correctly, you don't need the variable `result` at all, since you're calling the second function inside of the first one.. right?

Comment: done :) Sorry for my bad english and for my bad skills, im still learning since a few weeks :)

Comment: sorry for late answer, your code helped me to write my functions. Now i have it so as i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

My answer may look ugly, but it works. You can optimize it if you want.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION uploadbutton(arr character varying[]) 
  RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE

arr_data character varying[] := arr;
array_len integer;
ar_data text;
incr INTEGER := 1;
result_data TEXT;
start_scope text := '(';
end_scope text := ')';
ins_incr integer := 1;
next_val text := '';
BEGIN

    array_len := (select array_length(arr_data,1));

    WHILE incr <= array_len LOOP

        ar_data := CONCAT('''',arr_data[incr],'''');
        IF (result_data IS NULL) THEN 
            result_data := CONCAT(result_data,'',ar_data);
        ELSE 
            result_data := CONCAT(result_data,',',ar_data);
        END IF;

        ins_incr := ins_incr + 1;

        IF (ins_incr = 4) THEN
                result_data := CONCAT(start_scope,result_data,end_scope);
            next_val := CONCAT(next_val,result_data);
            result_data := NULL;
            ins_incr := 1;
        END IF;
        incr := incr + 1;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN CONCAT(next_val,'(',result_data,')');
END $$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Sample:

```
SELECT uploadbutton(array ['59373033336415021231','5','a','59373033335915022fff','5','b','59373033335915022CCC','6','C','59373033335915022KKK','77','KK'])
```